# Where can I find the arch/setup source?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, archlinux, gentoo, pacman-package-manager

Where can I find the arch/setup source?

I did not find in ftp://ftp.archlinux.org/sources/

Who knows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for the [Arch Installer Framework](https://github.com/Dieterbe/aif)?